# Updating DLL file to new .Net Framework

Tags: .net, dll, frameworks

I have an old .Net application build in framework 1.1, now I want to update the application to Framework 3.5. Do I have to rewrite the entire application or can I update the DLL files? If DLL file is an option to update, how shall I proceed?

Comment: Are you adding any new functionality which actually uses the .net framework 3.5 or is it just support for 3.5?

Comment: Leave the DLL's as is unless you want to use new functionality of newer frameworks. The application (exe) decides what runtime to use.

Comment: I am not adding any new functionality, I am upgrading my OS to Windows 8.1 which doesn't support framework 1.1. So its just for the support for 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your project. Go to Project right click on it --> Properties ---> Application --> Select Target Framework(3.5 in your case) you wants....and then Select it and rebuild the solution. That's it!!

Comment: In my application there are 15-16 modules, so just in one go I am unable to to rebuild it!